# Launch a particular Program from Android TV Home Screen

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-tv, homescreen, leanback

I'm working on TV Recommendations / Home Screen Channels app.

I've successfully shown list of Programs from my App on Android TV Home Screen and able to launch VideoPlaybackActivity whenever user select any of the program from Home Screen.

**Issue:** Unable to launch a particular Video, which user has selected on Home Screen

Here is the code, I've written to launch programs in *VideoListingActivity*

```
public void dynamicPrograms() {

        for (Movie movie : movieArrayListHomeScreen) {

            Uri posterArtUri = Uri.parse(movie.getImageUrl(Movie.IMAGE_ICON));
            Uri previewVideoUri = Uri.parse(movie.getPlaybackUrl());

            PreviewProgram program = new PreviewProgram.Builder()
                    .setChannelId(channelId)
                    .setType(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.TYPE_MOVIE)
                    .setTitle(movie.getName())
                    .setDescription(movie.getName() + " description goes here")
                    .setPosterArtUri(posterArtUri)
                    //.setPreviewVideoUri(previewVideoUri)
                    .setInternalProviderId(String.valueOf(movie.getId()))
                    .setContentId(String.valueOf(movie.getId()))
                    .setIntentUri(Uri.parse(SCHEME + "://" + APPS_LAUNCH_HOST
                            + "/" + PLAY_VIDEO_ACTION_PATH + "/" + movie))
                    .build();

            Uri programUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                    .insert(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.CONTENT_URI, program.toContentValues());

            long programId = ContentUris.parseId(programUri);
            Log.d("programId:", String.valueOf(programId));
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I'm passing data using Intent, but not getting same in VideoPlaybackActivity, but If I use same Intent in an Activity (assume in Detail Activity) to call VideoPlaybackActivity then I'm getting data for a selected / particular video as I'm printing same in Logcat

This is what I am using in *VideoDetailsActivity* to play a selected Video in VideoPlaybackActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext (), VideoPlaybackActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra (VideoPlaybackActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, movie);
                                startActivity (intent);
```

But when I'm directly calling VideoPlaybackActivity from Android TV Home Screen (not getting value of a particular video in Logcat) therefore unable to launch VideoPlaybackActivity to play a particular Video

Manifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.activity.VideoPlaybackActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="androidtvhomescreenchannels"
                android:host="com.androidtv.hsc"
                android:pathPrefix="/playvideo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**NOTE:** Even, I would like to know which particular program I selected from Home Screen, I would love to see Name of that Program / Movie in Logcat

Comment: Is it always showing 1st video when you select the row and click method is *onItemClicked*??

Comment: playing default video and that one is not part of row

Comment: for (Movie movie1 : movieArrayListHomeScreen)  is calling intent in loop. seems there is the issue.

Comment: so what you think, how it should be @Jay

Comment: Can you share the onItemClicked code, it would be good for analyze.

Comment: that's the only code I'm using as trying to launch particular Video in VideoPlaybackActivity from Home Screem itself, through Activities and Fragments, I already achieved that part... still like to see scroll above and see the Intent code I'm using in VideoDetailActivity to launch VideoPlaybackActivity

Answer (score 0):

Some reason when the Channel is clicked, the original intent which was set by  `.setIntent(intent)` on `new PreviewProgram.Builder()` is overwritten or lost for whatever reason.

The only thing i managed to do is to include the ID of the (movie/channel) with the `Uri` of the intent.

So instead of passing an object with

> ```
>                 .setIntentUri(Uri.parse(SCHEME + "://" + APPS_LAUNCH_HOST
>                         + "/" + PLAY_VIDEO_ACTION_PATH + "/" + movie))
> ```

just send the movieID as a valueType

> `int movieID;`
>
> ```
>                 .setIntentUri(Uri.parse(SCHEME + "://" + APPS_LAUNCH_HOST
>                         + "/" + PLAY_VIDEO_ACTION_PATH + "/" + movieID))
> ```

To extract the ID at the newly opened Activity:

https://github.com/android/tv-samples/blob/e3eb39fbcbc217939c1b621917f850e95c75895e/LeanbackShowcase/app/src/main/java/androidx/leanback/leanbackshowcase/app/rows/VideoPlaybackActivity.java#L98

```
String videoId = getVideoID(getIntent().getData());


 /**
 * This is the helper function to extract the videoId (an unique id which will not be
 * changed along with the transaction)
 */
private String getVideoID(Uri uri) {
    List<String> paths = uri.getPathSegments();
    if (paths.size() == 2 && TextUtils.equals(paths.get(0), PLAY_VIDEO_ACTION_PATH)) {
        return paths.get(1);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Obviously it would be much better if i could send the Object directly to the Activity like i normally do.